# Unity WWW api call not working in iOS devices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a an api which is called on some event. The api works on the Web platform and on Editor too, but do not work on iOS devices. Here is my code where I called the api:

> ```
>   string data = "{'UserName':'myUserName'," + 
>                   "'Password':'myPass'}";   
>   var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
>   var header = new Hashtable();
>   header.Add("content-type", "application/json");
>   header.Add("content-length", data.Length);    
>   Debug.Log("Time To Hit the api");
>   ////Now below is the api I am hitting////
>   WWW responseToken = new WWW(someLink, encoding.GetBytes(data), header); 
>   yield return responseToken;       
>   Debug.Log("Now get the response");
> ```

Well I needed this api to work on my iOS devices as well. On iOS device when this code runs, it prints the log statement 'Time To Hit the api', but it never prints 'Now get the response' log.

Please help me here, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html)?
I use it and works fine.

see example :

```
// Create a form object for sending high score data to the server
var form = new WWWForm();
// Assuming the perl script manages high scores for different games
form.AddField( "game", "MyGameName" );
 // The name of the player submitting the scores
form.AddField( "playerName", playName );
 // The score
form.AddField( "score", score );

// Create a download object
var download = new WWW( someLink, form );

// Wait until the download is done
yield download;

if(download.error) {
    print( "Error downloading: " + download.error );
    return;
} else {
    // show the highscores
    Debug.Log(download.text);
}
```

Comment: Typically answers should consist of more than just a link to a tool/library.  Perhaps explaining why it solves the problem and how to use it to solve the problem

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you for your comment. I add example code.

Comment: This works in Android, Windows, Windows Mobile but unfortunately not on iOS.  Could the iOS implementation on Unity be broken?  Do we need to set some sort of special flag in the XCode project somewhere to allow the Apple device to communicate on the internet?